# Kotlin and RxJava - Why is my Single.zip() not compiling?

Tags: rx-java, kotlin

I'm going a little crazy here. I'm trying to create an `Observable<BigDecimal>` extension function (against RxJava 2.x) to emit the average of the emissions, but I'm getting a compile error with the `Single.zip()` function. Does anybody have any ideas what I'm doing wrong? I tried to be explicit with all my types too and that didn't work...

```
import io.reactivex.Observable
import io.reactivex.Single
import java.math.BigDecimal


fun Observable<BigDecimal>.sum() = reduce { total, next -> total + next }

//compile error
fun Observable<BigDecimal>.average() = publish().autoConnect(2).let {
    Single.zip(it.sum().toSingle(), it.count()) {
        sum, count -> sum / BigDecimal.valueOf(count)
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: When asking about an error, post the error.

Comment: I was going to do that but forgot, will update later for reference to others.

Comment: What's the error??

Comment: Added screen clip above with error popup.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

Type inference mostly does not work for rxJava2. It's not a type inference problem actually. Kotlin usually generates extension methods to that replaces SAM with kotlin functional types, but this technic does not work for overridden methods for some reason.

More details here https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-13609

As an option, you could try to specify types for lambda arguments

```
fun Observable<BigDecimal>.average() = publish().autoConnect(2).let {
    Single.zip(it.sum().toSingle(), it.count(), BiFunction {
        sum: BigDecimal, count: Long ->
        sum / BigDecimal.valueOf(count)
    })
}
```

Comment: Thanks, giving answer to Stepan since it maximizes inference.

Comment: What if i have three or more Singles in the zip, BiFunction doesn't seem to work since it takes only two

Comment: @IzzoObella, in this case, you'll need to use Function3 instead of BiFunction

Comment: Its okay, i got a solution by using RxKotlin which has an extension function for that

Comment: nice. much cleaner looking that writing out the whole BiFunction declaration including generics like this. BiFunction<CurrencyData,CryptoCurrency, Pair<CurrencyData,CryptoCurrency>>{ a, b -> Pair(a,b)})

Answer (score 10):

Type inference is failing for some reason, there must be somehow multiple combinations of types that could be inferred in this context.

You can specify the types explicitly with a more traditional (and unfortunately more verbose) syntax, like this:

```
fun Observable<BigDecimal>.average() = publish().autoConnect(2).let {
    Single.zip(it.sum().toSingle(), it.count(), BiFunction<BigDecimal, Long, BigDecimal> {
        sum, count ->
        sum / BigDecimal.valueOf(count)
    })
}
```

**Update:**

I've just found out while working on a similar problem that the actual problem here is that Kotlin isn't able to infer which `Single.zip` overload you're trying to call. From the [official documentation](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/java-interop.html#sam-conversions):

> If the Java class has multiple methods taking functional interfaces,
>   you can choose the one you need to call by using an adapter function
>   that converts a lambda to a specific SAM type. Those adapter functions
>   are also generated by the compiler when needed.

So it turns out that using the more explicit SAM constructor solves this in itself, and gives you type inference back (basically, my previous answer was using a longer syntax than was actually required):

```
fun Observable<BigDecimal>.average(): Single<BigDecimal> = publish().autoConnect(2).let {
    Single.zip(it.sum().toSingle(), it.count(), BiFunction {
        sum, count ->
        sum / BigDecimal.valueOf(count)
    })
}
```

Comment: Ew... Okay I'll run this tomorrow and follow up if it works. If this can't be inferred that is unfortunate.

Comment: Hey, I've just updated my answer with a better solution.

Answer (score 4):

If type inferencing is the problem, one thing you can do is use [RxKotlin](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxKotlin)

```
implementation "io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxkotlin:$rxKotlinVersion"
```

RxKotlin specifically provides [SAM helpers](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxKotlin#sam-helpers) to help mitigate the issues with type inferencing issues.

In which case,

```
Singles.zip(..., ...)
```

would be able to work just fine without any ambiguity. Notice I am using `Singles` and not `Single`

Comment: Is it possible to use `Singles.zip(..., ...)` when I don't know the number of Singles (having them in a List)?

Comment: @Micer i think i am going to need some more context, it sounds like it would warrant its own question

Comment: I have N urls, I need to make N network calls and merge the result. I've created Singles and put them in the list. I couldn't use `Singles.zip(..., ...)`, because it accepts exact number of Single objects. I finally solved it by using `<T, R> Single<R> zip(final Iterable<? extends SingleSource<? extends T>> sources, Function<? super Object[], ? extends R> zipper)` from RxJava2 library. Thanks anyway. ;-)