# Observable.combineLatest type inference in kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, rx-java2, rx-binding

I'm using RxJava2, Kotlin-1.1 along with RxBindings in my project.

I have simple login screen with 'login' button disabled by default, I want to enable the button only when username and password edittext fields are not empty.

**LoginActivity.java**

```
Observable<Boolean> isFormEnabled =
    Observable.combineLatest(mUserNameObservable, mPasswordObservable,
        (userName, password) -> userName.length() > 0 && password.length() > 0)
        .distinctUntilChanged();
```

I'm unable to translate the above code from Java to Kotlin:

**LoginActivity.kt**

```
class LoginActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

  val disposable = CompositeDisposable()

  private var userNameObservable: Observable<CharSequence>? = null
  private var passwordObservable: Observable<CharSequence>? = null

  override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_login)
    initialize()
  }

  fun initialize() {
    userNameObservable = RxTextView.textChanges(username).skip(1)
        .debounce(500, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
    passwordObservable = RxTextView.textChanges(password).skip(1)
        .debounce(500, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS) 
  }

  private fun setSignInButtonEnableListener() {
    val isSignInEnabled: Observable<Boolean> = Observable.combineLatest(userNameObservable,
        passwordObservable,
        { u: CharSequence, p: CharSequence -> u.isNotEmpty() && p.isNotEmpty() })
  }
}
```

I assumed it's something related to type inference of the third argument in `combinelatest`, but I don't get the issue properly by reading the error message: 
[image: Type Inference issue]

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Your issue is that the compiler can't figure out which override of `combineLatest` to call, because multiple ones have functional interfaces as their third parameter. You can make the conversion explicit with a SAM constructor like this:

```
val isSignInEnabled: Observable<Boolean> = Observable.combineLatest(
        userNameObservable,
        passwordObservable,
        BiFunction { u, p -> u.isNotEmpty() && p.isNotEmpty() })
```

Ps. Thanks for asking this question, it helped me figure out that I was initially wrong about this one that turns out to be the same problem, which I've now updated with this solution as well. https://stackoverflow.com/a/42636503/4465208

Comment: Took me so long figure this out.

Comment: This [link](https://dev.to/amay077/rxjava-combinelatest-quick-example-e8b) may be helpful in connection with this answer.

Answer (score 40):

You can use [RxKotlin](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxKotlin) which gives you helper methods for SAM ambiguity issue.

```
val isSignInEnabled: Observable<Boolean> = Observables.combineLatest(
    userNameObservable,
    passwordObservable)
    { u, p -> u.isNotEmpty() && p.isNotEmpty() })
```

As you can see, in RxKotlin use `Observables` instead of `Observable`