# Observable.combineLatest cause error after updating to RxJava 2.x.x. - cannot infer type

Tags: android, kotlin, rx-java, rx-java2

Last few days I am trying to migrate my project from RxJava 1.x.x to RxJava 2.x.x. I have this simple method. Everything is OK if I use the Observables from rxjava 1.x.x (rx.Observable). However, when I replaced it with "new" observables (io.reactivex.Observable, I get an error saying : "Type inference failed. Please specify it explicitly"

```
fun <T1, T2, T3, R> combineLatestValue3Nullable(observable1: Observable<T1?>, observable2: Observable<T2?>, observable3: Observable<T3?>, merge: (T1, T2, T3?) -> R): Observable<R?> {
    return Observable.combineLatest(observable1, observable2, observable3) {
        value1, value2, value3 ->
        var result: R? = null
        if (value1 != null && value2 != null) {
            result = merge(value1, value2, value3)
        }
        result
    }
}
```

Do you have any idea what I do wrong? Can you please explain what exactly cause this error in RxJava 2?

Somebody ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42725749/observable-combinelatest-type-inference-in-kotlin)) had a problem very similar to this. However, they are using BiFuntion in their solution which accepts two arguments and creates a result. As you can see I use more arguments (3) so I can't use Bifunction here.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Observable.combineLatest type inference in kotlin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42725749/observable-combinelatest-type-inference-in-kotlin)

Comment: No, I wouldn't say that this is a duplicate question. I saw their solution and it doesn't work for me. They are using BiFuntion which accepts two arguments and creates a result. As you can see I use more arguments  (3) so I can't use Bifunction here.

Comment: You're right, this is a different question indeed. If it was only more arguments, I think you could just use `Function3` the same way as the `BiFunction` example, but you have generics as well to complicate things. I think this will only work if you write out the full `object` syntax to create a `Function3`, with explicit types.

Comment: You can't use nulls (and nullable types) in RxJava 2. That function can never be called because Observables of nullable types don't exist. If you absolutely have to recognize absence of a value, use Optional.

Comment: @PepaHruška Interesting. I answer the question just now. please see [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45120698/rewrite-java-code-using-method-reference-to-kotlin). if you have some doubts add a comment below my answer.

Comment: @zsmb13 I didn't know about Function3, Function4 etc. I just put the Function3 there and it worked. I just had to remove nullable return type of this method. Thanks

Comment: @EugenPechanec Thanks for advice. I didn't know about Optional class - it may be handy.

Comment: @holi-java I saw your answer. Thanks for explaining this so thoroughly. It 's interesting

Comment: @PepaHruška Not at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the end I found a solution based on given advice above. The first thing which should be mentioned is the fact that we shouldn't return nullable Observable at all. If we need to check values passed to combineLatest we should do it before instead of checking it inside combineLatest.

When we remove nullability the method looks like this:

```
fun <T1, T2, T3, R> combineLatest(observable1: Observable<T1>, observable2: Observable<T2>, observable3: Observable<T3>, merge: (T1, T2, T3) -> R): Observable<R> {
    return Observable.combineLatest(observable1, observable2, observable3, Function3 {
        value1, value2, value3 ->
        merge(value1, value2, value3)
    })
}
```

The only additional thing which I had to change is to replace lambda with Function3 - it solves the problem of type inference.

If you have just two values for combineLatest you can use BiFuntion instead of Function3.

If you need to pas for example 6 variables to combineLatest you can use Function6 etc.

See all the variants below:

```
fun <T1, T2, R> combineLatest(observable1: Observable<T1>, observable2: Observable<T2>, merge: (T1, T2) -> R): Observable<R> {
    return Observable.combineLatest(observable1, observable2, BiFunction {
        value1, value2 ->
        merge(value1, value2)
    })
}

fun <T1, T2, T3, R> combineLatest(observable1: Observable<T1>, observable2: Observable<T2>, observable3: Observable<T3>, merge: (T1, T2, T3) -> R): Observable<R> {
    return Observable.combineLatest(observable1, observable2, observable3, Function3 {
        value1, value2, value3 ->
        merge(value1, value2, value3)
    })
}

fun <T1, T2, T3, T4, R> combineLatest(observable1: Observable<T1>, observable2: Observable<T2>, observable3: Observable<T3>, observable4: Observable<T4>, merge: (T1, T2, T3, T4) -> R): Observable<R> {
    return Observable.combineLatest(observable1, observable2, observable3, observable4, Function4 {
        value1, value2, value3, value4 ->
        merge(value1, value2, value3, value4)
    })
}

fun <T1, T2, T3, T4, T5, R> combineLatest(observable1: Observable<T1>, observable2: Observable<T2>, observable3: Observable<T3>, observable4: Observable<T4>, observable5: Observable<T5>, merge: (T1, T2, T3, T4, T5) -> R): Observable<R> {

    return Observable.combineLatest(observable1, observable2, observable3, observable4, observable5, Function5 {
        value1, value2, value3, value4, value5 ->
        merge(value1, value2, value3, value4, value5)
    })
}

fun <T1, T2, T3, T4, T5, T6, R> combineLatest(observable1: Observable<T1>, observable2: Observable<T2>, observable3: Observable<T3>, observable4: Observable<T4>, observable5: Observable<T5>, observable6: Observable<T6>, merge: (T1, T2, T3, T4, T5, T6) -> R): Observable<R> {
    return Observable.combineLatest(observable1, observable2, observable3, observable4, observable5, observable6, Function6 {
        value1, value2, value3, value4, value5, value6 ->
        merge(value1, value2, value3, value4, value5, value6)
    })
}

fun <T1, T2, T3, T4, T5, T6, T7, R> combineLatest(observable1: Observable<T1>, observable2: Observable<T2>, observable3: Observable<T3>, observable4: Observable<T4>, observable5: Observable<T5>, observable6: Observable<T6>, observable7: Observable<T7>, merge: (T1, T2, T3, T4, T5, T6, T7) -> R): Observable<R> {
    return Observable.combineLatest(observable1, observable2, observable3, observable4, observable5, observable6, observable7, Function7 {
        value1, value2, value3, value4, value5, value6, value7 ->
        merge(value1, value2, value3, value4, value5, value6, value7)
    })
}

fun <T1, T2, T3, T4, T5, T6, T7, T8, R> combineLatest(observable1: Observable<T1>, observable2: Observable<T2>, observable3: Observable<T3>, observable4: Observable<T4>, observable5: Observable<T5>, observable6: Observable<T6>, observable7: Observable<T7>, observable8: Observable<T8>, merge: (T1, T2, T3, T4, T5, T6, T7, T8) -> R): Observable<R> {
    return Observable.combineLatest(observable1, observable2, observable3, observable4, observable5, observable6, observable7, observable8, Function8 {
        value1, value2, value3, value4, value5, value6, value7, value8 ->
        merge(value1, value2, value3, value4, value5, value6, value7, value8)
    })
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you using [RxKotlin](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxKotlin)? If not, I'd suggest giving that a try as it has SAM helpers for various methods, including `combineLatest`, which is one of the methods affected. See their [docs](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxKotlin#sam-helpers) for more info.

Comment: Yes, I am using RxKotlin.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. Then I saw that Kotlin has a function with the same name, and it is used by default. So I just imported the RxJava function explicitly and this helped me get rid of the error:

```
import io.reactivex.functions.Function3
```