# Rewrite Java code in Kotlin using Function Reference occurs SAM types conflict

Tags: java, lambda, kotlin, rx-java2, method-reference

I have an example Java code using method reference that I want to rewrite to Kotlin. Java version is using method reference, solution is short and clear. But on the other hand I cannot use method reference in Kotlin. The only version that I've managed to write is one presented below. It seems like `Function3 { s: String, b: Boolean, i: Int -> combine(s, b, i) }` could be written in cleaner way (if possible method reference would be perfect).

I'm new to Kotlin so I'll be grateful for any clues.

**Java**

```
import io.reactivex.Observable;

public class TestJava {

    Observable<String> strings() {
        return Observable.just("test");
    }

    Observable<Boolean> booleans() {
        return Observable.just(true);
    }

    Observable<Integer> integers() {
        return Observable.just(1);
    }

    void test() {
        Observable.combineLatest(strings(), booleans(), integers(),
                this::combine);
    }

    double combine(String s, boolean b, int i) {
        return 1.0;
    }
}
```

**Kotlin**

```
import io.reactivex.Observable
import io.reactivex.functions.Function3

class TestKotlin {

    fun strings(): Observable<String> {
        return Observable.just("test")
    }

    fun booleans(): Observable<Boolean> {
        return Observable.just(true)
    }

    fun integers(): Observable<Int> {
        return Observable.just(1)
    }

    fun test() {
        Observable.combineLatest(strings(), booleans(), integers(),
                Function3 { s: String, b: Boolean, i: Int -> combine(s, b, i) })
    }

    fun combine(s: String, b: Boolean, i: Int): Double {
        return 1.0
    }
}
```

**EDIT**

Following method references in Kotlin gives an error.

```
fun test() {
    Observable.combineLatest(strings(), booleans(), integers(), this::combine)
}

fun test() {
    Observable.combineLatest(strings(), booleans(), integers(), TestKotlin::combine)
}
```

> None of the following functions can be called with the arguments
>   supplied:  @CheckReturnValue @SchedulerSupport public final fun  combineLatest(p0: ((Observer) -> Unit)!, p1: ((Observer) -> Unit)!, p2:
>   ((Observer) -> Unit)!, p3: ((???, ???, ???) -> ???)!):
>   Observable<(???..???)>! defined in io.reactivex.Observable
>   @CheckReturnValue @SchedulerSupport public open fun  combineLatest(p0: ObservableSource!, p1: ObservableSource!, p2:
>   ObservableSource!, p3: io.reactivex.functions.Function3!):
>   Observable<(???..???)>! defined in io.reactivex.Observable
>   @CheckReturnValue @SchedulerSupport public open fun  combineLatest(p0: Function!, out
>   (???..???)>!, p1: Int, vararg p2: ObservableSource!):
>   Observable<(???..???)>! defined in io.reactivex.Observable

**EDIT 2**

[RxKotlin](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxKotlin) solves issue mentioned in answer.

```
import io.reactivex.rxkotlin.Observables

class TestKotlin {

    fun test() {
        Observables.combineLatest(strings(), booleans(), integers(), this::combine)
    }

}
```

Comment: first, I'm not the downer. have you tried?

Comment: _"I cannot use method reference in Kotlin"_ Why not?

Comment: @holi-java of course I tried

Comment: @AleksanderMielczarek have you tried : `combineLatest(strings(), booleans(), integers(), this::combine)`  in Kotlin?

Comment: @holi-java see edited question

Comment: @AleksanderMielczarek I see it clearly. you try to reference a member function as a static function. you need to see https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/reflection.html#function-references

Comment: @holi-java using this::combine has same error

Comment: @AleksanderMielczarek which error you obtained? type inference?

Comment: @holi-java error added to question

Comment: @AleksanderMielczarek this is because rx-java2 has more than one `combineLatest` methods, it doesn't know where to go. it is not the problem of reference function.

Comment: @holi-java can you explain me than why Java can use method reference whereas Kotlin cannot?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can also using [Function Reference Expression](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/reflection.html#function-references) in Kotlin just like as Method Reference Expression in Java. for example, the `combine` function reference as `KFunction3` in Kotlin as below:

```
val f: kotlin.reflect.KFunction3<String, Boolean, Int, Double> = this::combine
```

In java, Method Reference Expression can assign to any **compatible** [Functional Interface](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/FunctionalInterface.html), but you can't assign a [Function Reference Expression](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/reflection.html#function-references) to any Function types even if they are **compatible**, for example:

```
val f:io.reactivex.functions.Function3<String,Boolean,Int,Double> =this::combine
//                                                type mismatch error     ---^
```

Indeed, Kotlin using [SAM Conversions](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/java-interop.html#sam-conversions) to convert lambda/[Function Reference Expression](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/reflection.html#function-references) into an implementation of Java [Functional Interface](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/FunctionalInterface.html), which means Kotlin does something like as below:

```
fun test() = TODO()

val exector:Executor = TODO()

exector.execute(::test)

//::test compile to java code as below:
Runnable task = new Runnable(){
   public void run(){
      test();
   }
};
```

**Why** did Method Reference Expression can works fine in Java, but using [Function Reference Expression](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/reflection.html#function-references) is failed in Kotlin?

Base on the above, and you can see there are many overloaded `combineLatest` methods in [rx-java2](/questions/tagged/rx-java2). for example, the following two can't make Kotlin using [Function Reference Expression](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/reflection.html#function-references) correctly:

```
combineLatest(
       ObservableSource<out T1>,
       ObservableSource<out T2>,
       ObservableSource<out T3>, 
       Function3<T1, T2, T3, out R>
)

combineLatest(
       ObservableSource<out T1>,
       ObservableSource<out T2>,
       ObservableSource<out T3>, 
       ObservableSource<out T4>, 
       Function4<T1, T2, T3, T4, out R>
)
```

As I said Kotlin using [SAM Conversions](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/java-interop.html#sam-conversions) to convert a lambda/[Function Reference Expression](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/reflection.html#function-references) to a Java [Functional Interface](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/FunctionalInterface.html), but it can't assign to a Java [Functional Interface](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/FunctionalInterface.html) directly.

The 4th parameter of the `combineLatest` method in Kotlin, the compiler can't infer its type at all, since the 4th parameter type can be `io.reactivex.functions.Function3` or `ObservableSource`. because `ObservableSource` is also a Java [Functional Interface](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/FunctionalInterface.html).

When you meet [SAM Conversion](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/java-interop.html#sam-conversions) conflict like as this, you can using an **adapter function** that converts a lambda to a specific SAM type, for example:

```
typealias RxFunction3<T1, T2, T3, R> = io.reactivex.functions.Function3<T1,T2,T3,R>

val f: RxFunction3<String, Boolean, Int, Double> = RxFunction3{ s, b, i-> 1.0}
```

So you must using an adaption before using lambda/[Function Reference Expression](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/reflection.html#function-references), for example:

```
typealias RxFunction3<T1, T2, T3, R> = io.reactivex.functions.Function3<T1,T2,T3,R>

fun <T1,T2,T3,R> KFunction3<T1,T2,T3,R>.toFunction3(): RxFunction3<T1, T2,T3,R> {
    return RxFunction3 { t1, t2, t3 -> invoke(t1, t2, t3) }
}
```

**Then** you can using [Function Reference Expression](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/reflection.html#function-references) as below, for example:

```
Observable.combineLatest(
        strings(),
        booleans(), 
        integers(), 
        //             v--- convert KFunction3 to RxFunction3 explicitly
        this::combine.toFunction3()
)
```

Comment: Thank you for this answer:). Until today I was unaware that such a problem exists. Just found RxKotlin https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxKotlin that solves this problem.

Comment: @AleksanderMielczarek Not at all. I find the problem in rx-java2 just now too. I never used [tag:rx-java2], :).

Comment: Use `import io.reactivex.rxkotlin.Observables` instead of a regular observable. The class description reads "SAM adapters to aid Kotlin lambda support"

Answer (score 4):

@holi-java Answer is great, it explains why this problem occurs, here I'm providing a quick fix for those who just want to get rid of the problem:

In `rxJava2` use `io.reactivex.rxkotlin.Observables` instead of `io.reactivex.Observable` to combine your observables:

```
Observables.combineLatest(src1, src2, ::yourFunction)
```

This should work out of the box.