# Cannot call specific timeout overload in Observable; kotlin cannot match the arguments

Tags: android, kotlin, rx-java2

I'm not entirely sure if this is a Kotlin issue or an RxJava issue but I'm leaning on the former.

I'm trying to call a specific [timeout](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/javadoc/io/reactivex/Observable.html#timeout-io.reactivex.functions.Function-io.reactivex.ObservableSource-) overload on an Observable, and the kotlin compiler won't let me.  Here's the example code:

```
fun <T, U> Observable<T>.emitOnTimeout(item:T, itemPredicate:(T)->ObservableSource<U>):Observable<T> {
    return this.publish {
        it.timeout( itemPredicate,
                Observable.just(item).concatWith(Observable.error(Exception()))
        ).retry()
    }
}
```

The compiler complains on the timeout call with the following:

```
 None of the following functions can be called with the arguments supplied: 
@CheckReturnValue @SchedulerSupport public final fun <V : Any!> timeout(p0: ((T) -> (ObservableSource<(U#1 (type parameter of com.smartlinxsolutions.clockprototype.views.badgeentry.emitOnTimeout)..U#1?)>..ObservableSource<U#1!>?)..((T) -> ObservableSource<U#1!>!)?), p1: ((Observer<in T!>) -> Unit)!): Observable<T!>! defined in io.reactivex.Observable
@CheckReturnValue @SchedulerSupport public final fun <U : Any!, V : Any!> timeout(p0: ((Observer<in (???..???)>) -> Unit)!, p1: ((T) -> ObservableSource<(???..???)>!)!): Observable<T!>! defined in io.reactivex.Observable
@CheckReturnValue @SchedulerSupport public final fun <U : Any!, V : Any!> timeout(p0: ObservableSource<(???..???)>!, p1: Function<in T!, out ObservableSource<(???..???)>!>!): Observable<T!>! defined in io.reactivex.Observable
@CheckReturnValue @SchedulerSupport public final fun <V : Any!> timeout(p0: Function<in T!, out ObservableSource<(???..???)>!>!, p1: ObservableSource<out T!>!): Observable<T!>! defined in io.reactivex.Observable
@CheckReturnValue @SchedulerSupport public final fun timeout(p0: Long, p1: TimeUnit!): Observable<T!>! defined in io.reactivex.Observable
```

I'm not even sure where Kotlin is getting the overloads that take an observer lambda.  Again, it can't seem to match the call even though the arguments should match exactly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to [this article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45120698/rewrite-java-code-in-kotlin-using-function-reference-occurs-sam-types-conflict?rq=1) which didn't come up until I posted this question, I was able to determine how to resolve the ambiguity, which has to do with the SAM types conflict issue that Kotlin runs into every now and then.

Anyway, change the code to this:

```
fun <T, U> Observable<T>.emitOnTimeout(item:T, itemPredicate:(T)->ObservableSource<U>):Observable<T> {
    return this.publish {
        it.timeout( io.reactivex.functions.Function(itemPredicate),
                Observable.just(item).concatWith(Observable.error(Exception()))
        ).retry()
    }
}
```

And the code will compile as expected.