# Generic Function References in Rx and Kotlin -- type inference failed

Tags: android, kotlin, rx-java, rx-java2, rx-kotlin

I am writing a method in Kotlin:

```
fun fetchDepositSession(): Completable =
        Observable.fromIterable(session.accounts)
                .map(DepositSession::DepositAccount)
                .toList()
                .doOnSuccess(depositSession::depositAccounts::set)
                .flatMapObservable(Observable::fromIterable)
                .map(DepositSession.DepositAccount::account::get)
                .toCompletable()
```

The line `.flatMapObservable(Observable::fromIterable)` is causing an error:

[image]

Comment: Observable<T>.fromIterable is a generic static function.  In the way you're currently using it, you're not declaring the type params, so there's no way to resolve the generic type.  When you pass a value in as a parameter, there is, but not in the use case you're providing, since you're not providing a param.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

RxJava and Kotlin inferring types don't work that well. There is a couple of issues like [KT-13609](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-13609) and [KT-14984](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-14984).

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42635968/kotlin-and-rxjava-why-is-my-single-zip-not-compiling) that is relative to the problem. There is also an [issue in RxKotlin's Github](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxKotlin/issues/103) talking about it.

Anyway, you can always use:

```
.flatMapObservable { Observable.fromIterable(it) }
```